# Handle SQL variable so that one value gets treated one way and all others differently

Tags: sql

Im currently making a sql script for either getting all the entries in a table or just a few. Due to the program limitations i can only use sql to get my result.
 Before the script is run you can set variables. These can not be empty.
The question is that i need to put a value into the variable and then in WHERE search for the number spesified or all numbers.

```
@_PARA_DATE=From date#01.01.2015
@_PARA_MIN_PERC=%#1
@_PARA_PLACE_NUMBER=PLACE#All results

select *
from 
Table_1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table2_nr = table_1.nr
INNER JOIN Table_3 ON Table3_nr = table_1.nr
INNER JOIN Table_4 ON Table4_nr = table_1.nr
WHERE 
(@_PARA_DATE BETWEEN Table_1.fromdate AND Table_1.todate) 
AND table_1.perc >= @_PARA_min_perc

if @_PARA_PLACE_NUMBER <> 'All results'
AND table_1.placenr = @_PARA_PLACE_NUMBER
```

Comment: Can you specify @number = NULL ?

Comment: @number cant be NULL is has to contain a value due to how the system is set up. The pre excecution variables are set like this:
@_PARAMETER=Labelbeforeinput#input
then it comes out as a form With an input Box were you can input a value into @_PARAMETER

Comment: Which DBMS is that? Looks like SQL Server/T-SQL?

Comment: Im not sure, i get Access to the database from a program that lets you make/run sql scripts from inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set @number = NULL then the WHERE clause is simple:

```
WHERE Isnull(@number, id_number) = id_number
```

This way if you pass @number <> null then the where clause returns @number = id_number else it will return id_number=id_number [tautology] so everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause should be

```
WHERE
(@number = 'some number' and id_number = @number) OR
(@number = 'everything')
```

Note that you can use NULL for better handling

```
 WHERE
    (@number is not null and id_number = @number) OR
    (@number is null)
```

If you want to return all rows, just pass NULL to the variable